# Software to visualize photography rules

Tags: windows, gratis, photography

In photography, there are several best practices or composition rules, e.g.

- the [rule of thirds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_thirds)
- the [golden ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio)
- symmetry

I am looking for a software that

- can add overlays (or otherwise visually indicate) of these rules to images in all rotations
- is very easy to use
- can save an image with overlay
- works on Windows
- is gratis

I don't

- need editing features
- want to implement it myself